# Plotting with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I was just wondering how can I plotting this kind of chart and data in *Seaborn*:

**data.csv:**

```
1,2,3
2007,05,06
2007,05,06
2007,05,08
2007,05,08
2007,05,12
2007,05,15
2007,05,16
...
```

barchart which I wanted to plot:

[image]

I would appreciate if someone knows how to plot this kind of bar chart with *Seaborn* with my data.

Comment: Just use the built-in [pandas plotting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots)

Comment: Are you columns done in 1 = year, 2 = month, 3 = value? Or they're all related to time and you're doing count?

Comment: @Leb 1= year, 2=month (3 is not here important, not included in bar chart) as you can see the example, one is based on months and the other based on year. Based on month, for example i count all Jan. in range of my year

Comment: I think that means: 1=year, 2=value where you have 12 rows per year, each row being the value for a specific month. if 2=month (number of the month, e.g. 1=january, you shouldn't have (2007,05) more than once!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data you provided it wasn't possible to create the plot so I made a small sample to test it on. It was kind of long because you need to manipulate the data. The main idea is to understand that stacked bar plots are additive regular bar plots.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# sample data - 3rd column ignored
data = """
year,month,count
2007,05,06
2007,05,06
2007,06,08
2007,06,08
2008,05,12
2008,05,15
2008,06,16
    """
# read data
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter=',')

groups = df.groupby(['year','month'])
plot_data = groups.count() # obtain count of year and month multi-index

# additive barplot (May and June)
sns.barplot(x = plot_data.reset_index(level=1).index.unique(), y = plot_data.sum(axis=0, level=1)['count'], data=df , color = "red", ci=None)
# single bottom plot (in this case May only or "05")
bottom_plot = sns.barplot(x = plot_data.reset_index(level=1).index.unique(), y = plot_data.reorder_levels(['month','year']).loc[5]['count'], color = "#0000A3")

bottom_plot.set_ylabel("Count")
bottom_plot.set_xlabel("Year")

plt.show()
```

[image]

The process can be increased to include all 12 months, but I'm not aware of a single code that would do that without manipulating the data.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas, you can make a [stacked barplot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-barplot) with simply:

```
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

So you just have to load or reshape your data first to have the months as columns and the year as index:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
# sample data - 3rd column ignored
data = """
1,2,3
2007,05,06
2007,05,06
2007,06,08
2007,06,08
2007,05,06
2007,05,06
2007,06,08
2007,06,08
2007,05,06
2007,05,06
2007,06,08
2007,06,08
2008,03,12
2008,09,15
2008,02,16
2008,04,12
2008,05,15
2008,06,16
2008,03,12
2008,08,15
2008,02,16
2008,09,12
2008,05,15
2008,06,16
    """
# read data
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter=',',names= ['year','count','ignore'],header=0,index_col='year')
nyears = len(np.unique(df.index.values))
df['month']=np.tile(np.arange(1,13),nyears)
#df.drop('ignore',1)
df.pivot(columns='month',values='count').plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```